# SQLSTATE connection refused while creating database

Tags: database, mamp, symfony6

I am stuck with this error while trying to create a database on Symfony 6:

```
An exception occured in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

[image: doctrine:database:create error]

I am on macOs, using MAMP.

Comment: Are you sure MAMP is turned on?

Comment: yes everything is on